# Loading an external mobile website into Ionic's InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser, ngcordova

[Flarum](https://discuss.flarum.org/) is a new-age forum software and it has a brilliant mobile web app that works incredibly well on iOS/Android's chrome. It has lots of functionality such as swiping discussions, tapping on replies etc etc.

My goal is to load that same mobile web app from an Ionic hybrid app. The first thing I tried loading the mobile web app from an iFrame.  This caused a lot of problems. Initially the page wouldn't even scroll, only after a couple session of serious google-fu was I able to get the scrolling to work, that too it was very choppy.

Then I started looking at ngCordova's InAppBrowser.  The problem is I can't seem to get the same functionality as loading it from Chrome within iOS/Android. Scrolling works fine, but the other functionality is missing ie swiping of discussion and many other things.

Is this a limitation within Ionic/ngCordova, or is there something that I should look at ? I've looked at the documentation and followed the steps from [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/)

Any tips, pointers, or sample apps would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

**tl;dr**: I want to load a mobile website from Ionic ngCordova's InAppBrowser, but can get the same functionality as loading it from chrome/safari on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

JS

```
window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_system’);   //Loads in the system browser 
window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_blank’);    //Loads in the InAppBrowser
window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_blank’, ‘location=no’); //Loads in the InAppBrowser with no location bar
window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_self’); //Loads in the Cordova web view
```

HTML

```
<ion-view title="Test Page">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
            <a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.nraboy.com/contact', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
                Open a Browser
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.twitter.com/nraboy', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
                Open a Twitter Client or Browser
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/+NicRaboy', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
                Open a Google+ Client or Browser
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Source https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/

Comment: Hi Raj, Thanks for the effort.  I did come across this when I was looking around for answers to this.  Unfortunately this doesn't seem to solve the problem, although I did try this out again.  Didn't get it to work on iOS emulator or my phone. 
I feel the solution would (probably) have to do with ngCordova which is Ionic's implementation of Cordova's library.

Comment: Yes you will have to include ngcordova.js